# Is there a better way to write str(len(myList))?

Tags: python

For example i'm printing something like:

```
print ('Number of Elephants less than %s: %s' % (str(floatB),str(len(myList))))
```

That ends with 4 brackets and doesn't feel very pythonic! Is there a better way? It's not really a performance thing, but I'm just going through the code and want to make it a little cleaner than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lose the `str()` calls:

```
print('Number of Elephants less than %s: %s' % (floatB, len(myList)))
```

This has exactly the same effect as your original code, since `%s` results in an automatic call to `str()` for the argument in question.

Note that instead of `%s` you could use the more specific `%d` (for the integer) and `%e`, `%E`, `%f`, `%F`, `%g` or `%G` for the float. These [format specifiers](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) are more flexible in that they allow you to specify the number of digits to print etc.

Comment: I guess the second %s will be %d

Comment: @Sid You can use `%d` to ensure it's an integer, but `%s` will work as well. As the answer states, `%s` means "just pass it through `str` first".

Comment: thanks guys. interesting to learn about those format specifiers

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need for you to do str, you can do:

```
print 'Number of Elephants less than %s: %s' % (floatB, len(myList))
```

Comment: hey! one less bracket, but only for python 2 and not 3 :P